React Native/Expo Router Can't pass expo route as a prop to custom component
I am trying to pass a specific route as a prop for a button component in my application.
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

// Define a type for the props
type MyComponentProps = {
  text: string;
  route: string;
};

const ContinueButton: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ text, route }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Pressable
                style={({ pressed }) => [
                  styles.button,
                  pressed && styles.buttonPressed,
                ]}
                onPress={() => router.push(route)}
              >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{text}</Text>
        </Pressable>
  );
};


The line onPress={() => router.push(route)} is causing an issue im pretty sure. Before compiling vscode shows the error:

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RelativePathString | ExternalPathString | "/_sitemap" | /_sitemap?${string} | /_sitemap#${string} | "/(starting)" | "/(starting)/error" | /(starting)/error?${string} | /(starting)/error#${string} | ... 37 more ... | { ...; }'.ts(2345)

if I just go ahead and run it, it throws:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined


As the error suggests, route prop has the wrong type. The router.push() method only accepts valid path types as its argument. Therefore, the route prop should be of the appropriate type, for example:
import { RelativePathString } from "expo-router";

type MyComponentProps = {
    text: string;
    route: RelativePathString;
};

The TypeError you mentioned is not related with that issue and can be due to many things and it is hard to tell from the code you provided. Check out this question.

You need to show the receiving page and you include absolutely no data?
